# Ajax queries in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

My problem is that I do not know if there is any listener that checks if ajax requests in my webview have finished. On page that I have opened in webview (it is not my page, so I cannot modify scripts) there are some ajax handlers that modify the HTML of the page. For example after clicking a link window titled "Loading..." shows up, and after a short moment this window changes title and fills itself with the result of ajax query. Is there any way to find out that page content has changed? I hope that there is a better way than to start new Thread that checks every few seconds if there is string "Loading..." in page source...

Answer (score 0):

When Ajax sending request it receives success or error find it in your script.

Comment: Yes, they do, but so what? How to access them from Java?